# How to integrate the dilogarithms?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, special-functions, polylogarithm

$\def\Li{\operatorname{Li}}$
How can you integrate $\Li_2$? I tried from $0 \to 1$

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \Li_2(z) \,dz = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$

$$\frac{An + B}{n^2} + \frac{D}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$$

$$(An + B)(n+1) + D(n^2) = 1$$

Let $n = -1, \implies D = 1$
Let $n = 0, \implies B = 1$
Let $n = 1, \implies A = -1$

$$\frac{-n + 1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$$

$$= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-n + 1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} $$

The $1/n$ is the problem, it is the harmonic series, which diverges.

Comment: Hint: Telescoping series!

Comment: doesn't work, I've tried it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\mathrm{Li}_2(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k+1)k^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{k^2}-\frac1k+\frac1{k+1}\right)\\
&=\zeta(2)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac1k\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)\\[12pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
is a telescoping series.

---

Note that we only break $\left(\dfrac1k-\dfrac1{k+1}\right)$ into $\dfrac1k$ and $\dfrac1{k+1}$ when we are looking at *finite* sums. When considering infinite sums, it is kept together, and is equal to $\dfrac1{k(k+1)}$.

Comment: $\begin{align} &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{k^2}-\frac1k+\frac1{k+1}\right)\\
&=\zeta(2)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)\\ \end{align}$ How can you split the zeta?, all terms have to be convergent the harmonic series clearly isnt

Comment: @Amad27: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(k+1)}$ is convergent since each term is less than $\dfrac1{k^2}$. In fact, since $\dfrac1k-\dfrac1{k+1}\gt0$, the absolute convergence of this series is shown in the latter half of my answer.

Comment: Oh, so you are consider $1/k$ and $1/(k+1) = u$ as ONE term, so that is converges as a whole??

Comment: @Amad27: Precisely. Since $\displaystyle\frac1{(k+1)k^2} =\color{#C00000}{\frac1{k^2}} -\color{#00A000}{\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)}$, we can keep the red and green pieces together. The sum of each piece is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should look at your decomposition as

$$\frac1{n^2 (n+1)} = \frac1{n^2} - \frac1{n (n+1)}$$

The sum over the second term is easy, given that the indefinite sum is telescoping, i.e.,

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{n (n+1)} = 1-\frac1{N+1}$$

We take the limit as $N \to \infty$ and then we may view this as the infinite sum.  (Otherwise, as you say, there are convergence issues.)

Thus the sum in question is $$\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
=\left.\vphantom{\Large A}x\,{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{x}\right\vert_{0}^{1}
-\int_{0}^{1}x\,{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\overbrace{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{1}}
^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1^{n} \over n^{2}}\ =\
{\pi^{2} \over 6}}}}\ -\ 
\int_{0}^{1}x\ \overbrace{\bracks{-\,{{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}}}}
^{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{x}}}}\ \,\dd x
={\pi^{2} \over 6} +\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x}_{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{-1}}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{\pi^{2} \over 6} - 1} \approx {\tt 0.6449} 
\end{align}